# How do I minimise spotify to the system tray?

Tags: windows, windows-10, notification-area, spotify

I use alt+tab a lot and spotify keeps irritating me. I want it to sit quietly in the system tray and play the music. This is easy in VLC, all you have to do is click the VLC icon in the system tray but this doesn't seem to work for spotify.

Comment: Doesn't Spotify modify it's close window button behavior into a minimize to tray button?

Answer (score 8):

The minimize option of Spotify could be checked by following settings:

Go to settings / show advanced settings and find the setting "Close button should minimize Spotify to the tray".

[image]

Comment: There's no 'Advanced Setting' in my Spotify.

Comment: I no longer have this option in 2024, only `Close button should minimize the Spotify window`

Answer (score 1):

A few people are suffering with this issue as I was. The above answer is correct, however, in my situation and others, that option was already turned on. To fix the issue is as simple as turning the option off, close Spotify, reopen Spotify and re-enable the option. You should see the tray icon appear straight away. Hope this helps others